# Python tkinter setting label text from function

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a label in a tkinter window and a function which outputs the current date in spanish. I am trying to set the label text to the date given by the function but it doesnt work.

the code is the following:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Tarea Programada 2")
root.geometry("800x700+350+100")
fecha = Label(root, text=" ", font=('times',10), fg= 'black', bg= 'white', width = 30, height = 1)
fecha.place(x=551,y=100)

def horayfecha():
   dia = time.strftime("%A")
   fecha = time.strftime("%m")
   mes = time.strftime("%B")
      año = time.strftime("%Y")
   if dia == "Monday":
       dia = "Lunes"
   if dia == "Tuesday":
       dia = "Martes"
   if dia == "Wednesday":
       dia = "Miercoles"
   if dia == "Thursday":
       dia = "Jueves"
   if dia == "Friday":
       dia = "Viernes"
   if dia == "Satuday":
       dia = "Sabado"
   if dia == "Sunday":
       dia = "Domingo"
   if mes == "January":
       mes = "enero"
   if mes == "February":
       mes = "febrero"
   if mes == "March":
       mes = "marzo"
   if mes == "April":
       mes = "abril"
   if mes == "May":
       mes = "mayo"
   if mes == "June":
       mes = "junio"
   if mes == "July":
       mes = "julio"
   if mes == "August":
       mes = "agosto"
   if mes == "September":
       mes = "stiembre"
   if mes == "October":
       mes = "octubre"
   if mes == "November":
       mes = "noviembre"
   if mes == "December":
       mes = "diciembre"
   comp = ("San José, Costa Rica " + dia + " " + fecha + " de " + mes + " de " + año)
   fecha.setLabel("{}".format(comp))

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see several ways in which this code would not work, including improper indentation and concatenating `str` objects with `Label` objects. Please ensure that the indentation in this code is as it appears in your actual program, and then clarify what sort of problems you're seeing.

Comment: I was correcting the indentation as you were writting your comment. The problem I have is that the label stays white and no text is displayed

Comment: Apart from missing the `import` statements, you refer to undefined methods like `setLabel()`, you never actually call `horayfecha()`, and the statement assigning `año` is incorrectly indented. Also, you `format()` a string with no changes, your `if` structure is not good, and there's at least one typo (`'stiembre'`). Please read about how to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, `fecha` starts out as an instance of a label, then you use the same variable name in a function to refer to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had many problems, including missing imports, indentation, style, non-unique variable names, mixing up which variables refer to which objects, spelling errors (yes, those count, because they bother the user almost as much as crashing bugs), poor widget placement, strange string formatting, failure to call defined functions, function results that are thrown away instead of returned, and possibly more that I'm forgetting.

Here is a cleaned-up version of your code that works properly:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Tarea Programada 2")
root.geometry("800x700+350+100")

fecha = Label(root, text=" ", font=('times',10), fg= 'black', bg= 'white', width = 50, height = 1)
fecha.place(x=350,y=100)

def horayfecha():
    día, fecha, mes, año = time.strftime("%A %m %B %Y").split()

    días = {'Monday':'Lunes', 'Tuesday':'Martes', 'Wednesday':'Miércoles',
            'Thursday':'Jueves', 'Friday':'Viernes', 'Saturday':'Sábado', 'Sunday':'Domingo'}

    meses = {'January':'Enero', 'February':'Febrero', 'March':'Marzo', 'April':'Abril', 'May':'Mayo',
             'June':'Junio', 'July':'Julio', 'August':'Agosto', 'September':'Setiembre', 'October':'Octubre',
             'November':'Noviembre', 'December':'Diciembre'}

    return ' '.join(["San José, Costa Rica", días.get(día), fecha, "de", meses.get(mes), "de", año])

fecha.config(text=horayfecha())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you, I actually didn't know there were so many problems, and excuse my lack of knowledge, I am just starting to learn python

Comment: Glad to help. I highly recommend reading up on `tkinter` on [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).